# Canonical bundle of $S^1$ is trivial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I have to show that the canonical bundle of $S^1$ is trivial. The canonical bundle of $S^1=T^*S^1$ namely is equal to the cotangent bundle. But how I can show that this cotangent bundle is trivial? I have to show that it is isomorphic at a product like $(S^1)^*\times \mathbb{R}$...but i think isn't correct...please help!!

Comment: It's enough to show that $TS^1$ is trivial. Can you draw a nowhere-vanishing vector field on the circle?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh in my definition a vector bundle is trivial if it is isomorphic as vecor bundle to a product, in this case, $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$. I know that the vector field $v=x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y \frac{\partial}{\partial }$ is a nowhere-vanishing vector field on the circle...

Comment: Right! Now it's a straightforward lemma that a vector bundle of rank $r$ is trivial iff it has $r$ global sections which are linearly independent at each point. Apply that in your case...

Comment: By the way, I don't know what the notation $(S^1)^*$ means in your question. It seems like a typo.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh sorry but I don't see the connection. You may say that a vector bundle is a section of a tangent bundle? And if it is the case how can i show that these section are linearly independent?

Comment: Exactly: I say that a vector field is a section of the tangent bundle. (If you don't like that you can write a nowhere-zero section of the cotangent bundle instead.) What does it mean for a vector in a 1-dimensional vector space to be linearly independent?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh that it is not the zero vector...

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Ok. I have understood what you say. Only one more things...what is your definition of global section? where I can find a proof of the proposition that you have written before?

Comment: See Milnor--Stasheff, *Characteristic Classes*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will suffice to show that $TS^1$ is trivial, since the dual of a trivial bundle is trivial. That $TS^1$ is trivial follows from the general fact that a Lie group $G$ (such as $S^1$) has a trivial tangent bundle. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$. An explicit trivialization of $TG$ is $$\varphi:G\times\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow TG$$ $$(g,\xi)\mapsto (g,d_eL_g(\xi)),$$ where $d_eL_g:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow T_gG$ is the differential of left multiplication by $g$ at the identity $e$.